# How to log a NOT existing user? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need to log a user without creating it into the database. How can I do that?

I'm using PHP 7.3, laravel 5.8 and Apache2.

I tried this code (after reading [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#other-authentication-methods)) :

```
$user = new \App\User();
$user->password = \Hash::make("superpassword");
$user->email = "email@email.com";
$user->name = "Name";
Auth::setUser( $user );
Auth::login($user);

if (Auth::check()) {
                // the user is logged
                $request->session()->regenerate();
                $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
                $request->session()->put('userData', $user);
                $request->session()->regenerate();
                $request->session()->put('redirectTo', '/home');
                return redirect()->intended('/home');
}
```

After that, I made a redirect and the user seems not logged anymore.

I expect to find a way to log this user without creating it into the database. In the default login page, it must success.

(Sorry for my bad english, I hope I was clear)

Comment: Why did I get the downvote? Can anyone explain me? Thanks to all.

Comment: If you want something to be public, why put it behind a login?

Comment: I don't want it public. I have to make a api call into another project, check if that user exists and after that I want to make the login

Comment: Okay, so why do you need this thing to fake log somebody in? Either way I don't get it. Maybe somebody else will.

Comment: The user does not exits into this laravel project so if that user exists into the other database (which is not related with the laravel project) I have to find a way to make the login.
Can you suggest me another way to make this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without heavily modifying the built in `Auth` logic in Laravel. `Auth` relies on the User existing in the database, as it is fetched on every new request. What's the reasoning for not wanting to save this User?

Comment: We have different user: 1. admin user: they access through the built in Auth logic; 2. other user: they must access through the other project. Re-creating the user will cause duplicated data through different projects. It also means that we have to keep updated every user and other things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is, to create a custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) that runs before the auth middleware, and that executes your user initiation code before each request. Alternatively, you can create a custom [auth guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards), that contains your logic for fetching the currently authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, Laravel is going to pull the user from the database, but you don't have an entry in the database, you have a **User** object that logs in.  No `id`.  Thus, it will have a hard time carrying over from view to view without changing a bit of the basic `Auth`.

I've had a similar problem and solved it with a single DB user that mutated for each user you have from another DB.  Depending on what you are using it for and your level of security this may work -- but if this gets into anything non-public, I don't recommend this approach.

Basically, create a single user in the DB with a known `id`.  This is your non-existing user.  When a user comes in from the other database, instead of going through the logging of the fake user, just change the user's name in the DB to match the public user (with the known `id`) and log him in as this default 'non-existing' user.  If you have an issue with concurrency, make several as necessary.

This user's perms would be set according to the public nature of needs.

Comment: I can't use the same user because I will have a lot of concurrency problems that I can't handle. Edit: Users must use functionalities that requires to be unique and different users may access to different things. This can work if I have to show the same thing to everyone.